# Spring security - Authentication stops working after some days - reboot needed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I have an application develop on Spring 4.1.4 and Spring Security 4.0.2, deployed on a server with Apache Tomcat 8 and JDK 1.7.
It happens that after some days some users can't login anymore even if they specity correct user/password combination.
Restarting Tomcat fixes the problem.

Any suggestion?
May it be a session related issue?

This is my security configuration

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter"/>

    <custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>

    <session-management  invalid-session-url="/login.html?invalidSession=1" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/upload/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>

    <headers>
        <xss-protection block="false"/>
        <frame-options disabled="true"/>
        <cache-control/>
    </headers>

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login.html" 
        default-target-url="/index" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=1" 
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html?logout=1" invalidate-session="false" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <!-- <csrf disabled="true" /> -->

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    </port-mappings>
</http>

<beans:bean id="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" class="com.finconsgroup.mens.springsecurity.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter">
    <beans:property name="customSessionExpiredErrorCode" value="419"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="com.finconsgroup.mens.springsecurity.MensSwitchUserFilter">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="mensAuthenticationService"/>
    <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_switch_user"/>
    <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user"/>
    <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/index"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean name="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="mensAuthenticationService">
        <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="mensAuthenticationService" class="com.finconsgroup.mens.springsecurity.MensAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="mensDataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="my_query"/>
    <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="my_query"/>
    <beans:property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="my_query"/>
    <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Spring Security -->

<beans:bean id="mensPermissionEvaluator" class="com.finconsgroup.mens.springsecurity.MensPermissionEvaluator">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="securityExpressionHandler" 
        class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="mensPermissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<global-method-security
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled"
    secured-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="securityExpressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>

<!-- ================================================================== -->
<!-- ACL service                                                        -->
<!-- ================================================================== -->

<beans:bean id="aclService" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="mensDataSource" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="cacheManager">
                <beans:ref bean="mensEhCacheManager"/>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                        <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ACL_ADMIN"/>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="mensDataSource" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache" />
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <!-- Decides whether current principal can make ACL changes. See
             AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl Javadoc for the rules involved. -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:list>
                    <!-- Role required to change ACL ownership -->
                    <beans:ref bean="adminRole" />
                    <!-- Role required to change auditing details -->
                    <beans:ref bean="adminRole" />
                    <!-- Role required to change other ACL/ACE details -->
                    <beans:ref bean="adminRole" />
                </beans:list>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="adminRole" class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ADMIN" />
</beans:bean>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens, what did you expect to happen? It is only partially your security configuration, where is your user information stored (and retrieved) the configuration of the authentication manager isn't here.

Comment: I posted the full configuration in the main post. The problem is that it says that user/password are not correct.

Comment: That is the symptom on the front-end but is that also the issue on the backend? Isn't it just that your database cannot be queried anymore? I see you have a lot of custom classes make sure they work correctly and that your database transactions/resource handling is setup correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Most of the custom classes are actually empty, they just call the superclass, but I need them for futher evolutions. I think database is ok because if I try to login with a different user (usually I always use the same while developing) the login works well.

Comment: I just ran into this issue.  My application has been running fine for weeks, and all of a sudden spring security would no longer authenticate any of the correct credentials.  Restarting tomcat fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes restarting tomcat fixes the issue, but temporarely.
I found that a definitive way to fix the problem is changing the session-fixation-protection attribute to migrateSession

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem changing the session-fixation-protection attribute to migrateSession.
Now I have no need to restart Tomcat periodically.